# Dynamically adding data toggle and data target in li using jquery

Tags: wordpress

I am building the theme in word press and i want my modal to link to the menu links. I am trying to add data-toggle in Li using j query but no result is occurring.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    j Query("#menu-item-135").add("data-toggle", modal);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code it will add attributes in your menu

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu-item-69").attr("data-toggle",'modal');
});
</script>
```